# Combining two columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Let's say I have a dataframe that has, amnog others, two columns, date1, and date2.
Date1 is null when date2 is not, and vice-versa.

I want to create a column named "date".

I did this:

```
def setDate(s1, s2):
    if not isinstance(s1, str):
        return s2
    else:
        return s1
```

Then, I want to do something like:

```
data["DATE"] = data[["DATE1", "DATE2"]].apply(lambda x,y : setDate(x,y))
```

but I keep getting:

```
TypeError: ("<lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'", 'occurred at index DATE1')
```

How do I use apply on a dataframe to do what I want?

Comment: what error ? we can't read in your mind. Always put in question FULL error message (Traceback).

Comment: try with `lambda x:print(x)` - maybe it send both elements as one tuple/list

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data.DATE1.fillna(data.DATE2))
```

or if you want to keep the dtypes the way they are

```
data['DATE'] = data.DATE1.fillna(data.DATE2)
```